# How to set environment variable for SUMO_HOME (sumo-0.32.0) in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

After installing sumo-0.32.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I noticed that SUMO folder doesn't contain a bin directory!

The SUMO folder I checked is in the path: `/usr/share/sumo`
Is this the right sumo home directory, and how to set its environment variable step by step?

I installed sumo as indicated by its web page using the following three commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sumo/stable 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install sumo sumo-tools sumo-doc
```

Comment: See also [What is the difference between env, setenv, export and when to use?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368944/85039),  [Convention personal environment variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303041/85039),  [How to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117467/85039)

Comment: » "Warning: Environment variable SUMO_HOME is not set, using built in type maps" «  :  A warning is not an error, a waning is just "informational text". .... Did you install ´sumo´ ? → `cd sumo-0.32.0/ && sudo make install` ... or are you using sumo from the build location ?

Comment: I installed sumo as indicated by its web page using the following commands:
"
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sumo/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sumo sumo-tools sumo-doc
"

Comment: I installed sumo as indicated by its web page using the following three commands:
{
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sumo/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sumo sumo-tools sumo-doc
}
And when I got the warning, I tried to set the var permanently and appended this path: /usr/share/sumo the file etc/environment, but the same warning persist!
I noticed that the SUMO folder in this path doesn't contain a bin folder and contains tools folder only!

Comment: Have you [reloaded /etc/environment](https://superuser.com/q/339617/84807) after editing (reboot or re-login)? I think the environment variable, if needed by the application, should be set while installing SUMO using APT automatically, consider contacting the [developers of the SUMO package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~sumo).